# How to compare string in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i just want to know that, there is any way through which i can Compare a column value with Some String value.Something like this...
suppose `column name is SHIPMENT_EXPEDITE_HAWB` then can i have like this in plsql

```
SHIPMENT_EXPEDITE_HAWB=='PD'
```

Thaanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You just need one equals, not two.

```
IF shipment_expedite_hawb = 'PD' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Same');
END IF;
```

Comment: Always use single quotes if you're using IF in a function to avoid function compilation errors, e.g. 'PD' and not "PD"

Answer (score 7):

Just use the comparison operator `=`

E.g.

```
SHIPMENT_EXPEDITE_HAWB = 'PD'
```